# How to Remove Error Message in TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I remove the error message in `TextFormField` created by validator? I just want the red border because I don't have the space to show the error.

```
bool error = false;
 TextFormField ( 
      hintText:error?'please input productName':'',
      hintStyle:TextStyle(color: Colors.red), 
      validator:(v){  
       v.trim().length>0?error=false:error=true; return null; 
      }
 )
```

Comment: just `return` `null`

Comment: @Blasanka returning null will remove the functionality of validator

Comment: Check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61344323/4061501

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return an empty string which will still mark the borders red if not valid

```
 validator: (String value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
          return '';
     }
},
```

What I did to fix that was wrap the TextField with SizedBox and give a fixed height then want expand with error message

```
 SizedBox(
      height: SOME_FIXED_HEIGHT_INCLUDING_ERROR_MESSAGE'S_HEIGHT,
      child: TextField()
```

Comment: thank you ,I have try the empty String, it will push my widget upstare，can you please tell me the other solution,tks

Answer (score 89):

Try the code bellow.
No size adjustment for the error text, only the field border in red.

```
 TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
  ),
);
```

Comment: even get rid of the color, `errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0, color: Colors.transparent),`

Comment: @SamHamada does it make anyd difference?

Comment: This still makes the `TextFormField` taller for me in Flutter `3.0.5`. I can see it pushing down the content below the field.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum this is a hack but when I set the `height` to `0.01` instead of `0` on  Flutter `3.0.5`, it fixed the issue.

Comment: I also had to return an empty string on the validation.

Comment: @RichieTarkowski hack seems to work, while `TextStyle(height: 0)` is not working anymore (at least, I tested it on web)

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me. I like how it turned out.

No size adjustment or anything like that happens.

In the Constructor of `TextFormField`...

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        errorMaxLines: 1,
        errorText: '',
        errorStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          fontSize: 0,
          ),
         ),
```

If you want you could show errors on SnackBar...

Answer (score 6):

This works perfect for me. Looks pretty clean although you lose, of course, the error info coming from the validation.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
  ),
  validator: (_) => error ? '' : null,
  ),
```

Answer (score 6):

Just set `height` to `0` in `errorStyle`

```
InputDecoration(errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0)),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in two ways:

- #### Set `fontSize: 0.1` (workaround):

  ```dart
  TextFormField(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    validator: (input) {
      if (input == null || input.length < 3) return 'Too short';
      return null;
    },
    // This is the hack!
    decoration: InputDecoration(errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.1)),
  )
  ```
- #### Use a `FormField`:

  ```dart
  FormField<String>(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    validator: (input) {
      if (input == null || input.length < 3) return 'Too short';
      return null;
    },
    builder: (field) {
      final border = field.hasError
          ? UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
            )
          : null;

      return TextField(
        onChanged: field.didChange,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: border,
          focusedBorder: border,
        ),
      );
    },
  )
  ```

Comment: but return ' ' still will change the space of the widget

Comment: Alright, and what if you pass null there, that is do return null

Comment: if you return null, then it means there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

> just put helper text like that

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    helperText: ' ',
  ),
  validator: myValidator,
),
```

Comment: underrated comment

Answer (score 1):

```
errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0.01),
```

I set a height of TextStyle to 0.01 or 0.001. This worked for me.

but I think this is not a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a cleaner way but for now I am using `error` option with bool variable and then in hintText if error pass error message else `""`. Also color of text should be dependent on your error variable.

Find an example below

```
 final emailFieldColor =
        this._emailError == null ? //pass color: //pass error color;

               TextField(
                    controller: controllerName, //to access value
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: this._emailError == null
                            ? "Email"
                            : this._emailError,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: emailFieldColor),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: this._emailError == null
                            ? "hint text"
                            : this._emailError,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: 
                                this._emailError == null
                                ? //color1
                                : //color2),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: ```
bool error = false;

TextFormField (
    hintText:error?'please input productName':'',hintStyle:TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    validator:(v){
        v.trim().length>0?error=false:error=true;
        return null;
    })
```

I tried like this code, but only focus the widget will show the hintText,how can I show the hinttext when validate is false, or I missunderstand ,thank you

Comment: I think you got it working, if no let me know I will write an example for you.

Comment: I do like you say ,I hide the hintText before validate, but after validate ,the hintText is not show until focus on the widget,can you show me an example,thank you

Comment: I have added my example in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
hintText: validation ? NAME_TEXT_FIELD_HINT : 'Name is required!',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
              errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 14.0)),
          validator: (String value) {
            if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
              setState(() {
                validation = false;
              });
              return '';
            }
            return null;
```

This worked for me, setting the height to 0 + creating a boolean that made the error text replace the hintText instead (this could also be used for label text) I would imagine

Answer (score 0):

I know it's to late but maybe it helps someone, I set one by one how I like it, I mean, each border and messages like this:

```
 TextFormField(
                          controller: controller.emailController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.elliptical(120, 120),
                              ),
                            ),
                            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.elliptical(120, 120),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.elliptical(120, 120),
                              ),
                            ),
                            errorStyle:
                                TextStyle(height: 0, color: Colors.amber),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                            hintText: 'Username',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.elliptical(120, 120),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                          autofocus: true,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validator: (value) => '',
                          onSaved: controller.onEmailSaved,
                          onFieldSubmitted: controller.requestPasswordFocus,
                        ),
```

All of them are the same thing now, also the height is 0 for the error messages so it don't break my forms and the message is empty as someone reached above.

Answer (score 0):

So i used the hack of 0 height but found if you have 2 next to each other in a row you still end up with one higher than the other i had to also make the helper text 0.1

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
        helperText: '',
        helperStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
      ),
```