# How to hide error appearances when TextFormField is focused

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `TextFormField` for a form and custom validator method to return error message.
I'm trying to hide default error message and error border on the `TextFormField` when the text field get focused.

```
TextFormField(
   focusNode: _focusNode,
   validator: widget.validator,
   errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 5.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
   ),
   focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: const Color(0x1C707070),
        width: 0.5,
   ),
)
```

My problem is, the error border is overridden when the textfield get focused. And the underline turns red. I know this is how `TextFormField` works.

But what i'm trying to achieve is Hiding all error appearances including the Error message when the text field get focused.

Comment: The exact answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319435/495575).

Comment: @Aplit this questions is not about the form reset. Its about the customisation and the answer is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61344323/4061501).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've achieved desired UI by adding `errorStyle` & `focusedErrorBorder`.

```
errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
),
errorStyle: _focusNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(fontSize: 0, height: 0) : null,
focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
),
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution doesn't cover all cases. The better approach is the following:

- Set **autovalidateMode** property of Form to AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
- Add _skipValidation boolean property as flag in class
- In the validator method, return null if this flag is true.
- Add **onChanged**, **onTap**(optional) and **onSaved** functions inside  TextFormField. For the first two, simply set _skipValidation to true and on the other side, set flag as false in **onSaved**.
- Finally, before calling **currentState!.validate()** when user submits the form, use **currentState!.save()** to trigger onSaved method which we define above.

Comment: Validation properties and logics are skipped on the question and answer. The answer is about how we can change the error appearance when user has focus on the textfield.